# Why is Hanzo Hasashi not in Mortal Kombat 1 (2023)?

Tags: mortal-kombat

Until recently (2022), in the Mortal Kombat franchise, [Scorpion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorpion_(Mortal_Kombat))'s identity was of grandmaster Hanzo Hasashi, the leader and best ninja warrior of the Shirai Ryu clan.

In the reboot game "Mortal Kombat 1" from 2023, the identity of Scorpion is taken by Kuai Liang (which was Sub Zero in the older continuity after Scorpion killed Bi-Han the original Sub Zero), and he is part of the Lin Kuei clan. At the game's end story, Kuai Liang marries Harumi Shirai and forms the Shirai Ryu clan. Harumi was originally Hanzo's wife in the older continuity.

Where has Hanzo Hasashi, the original Scorpion, gone and does he have any role in that game and its continuity?

Comment: https://www.thegamer.com/mortal-kombat-1-brand-new-origin-for-hanzo-hazashi-original-scorpion-tower-ending/

Comment: https://www.dexerto.com/mortal-kombat/mortal-kombat-1-hanzo-original-scorpion-possible-tease-2252775/

Comment: Something something retconned

Comment: If you post the content in the links, I can accept the answer via the V tag. In short: The Shirai Ryu adopts Hanzo as a child by Smoke, and he is trained by Kuai Liang.

Comment: Honestly it would be better for you to self-answer. I've not played this game and the last Mortal Kombat thing I've seen was the 1995 film, so I've no idea what the current or accepted lore is.

Comment: So I think it is better to wait for someone who played the games to confirm it.

Comment: Personally, I'd add in some quotes from the interview above rather than relying on the wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1):

The following is taken from Wikipedia ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorpion_(Mortal_Kombat)#Netherrealm_Studio_games)):

> In ***Mortal Kombat 1***, the identity of **Scorpion** is rebooted to be **Kuai
> Liang**, while **Hanzo Hazashi**'s incarnation of Scorpion appears as an
> assist-based kameo character. In the game's story, the Lin Kuei serves
> Fire God Liu Kang as the protectors of Earthrealm, but Scorpion leaves
> the clan alongside Smoke after his brother, **Bi-Han**, reveals that he
> let their father die and betrays them to Shang Tsung. After Titan
> Shang's forces are defeated, Scorpion and Smoke escape to Japan to
> establish the **Shirai Ryu** clan, which becomes Earthrealm's new
> guardians. This timeline's version of **Hanzo Hasashi** appears in **Smoke**'s
> ending, where he is depicted as a young thief that Smoke recruits into
> the Shirai Ryu.

In addition:

> An alternate version of **Hanzo's Scorpion** appears as
> the first boss in Invasion Mode, where he threatens Liu Kang's
> timeline after discovering the only timeline he found **Harumi** alive in
> was one where she married Kuai Liang. After he is defeated, Liu Kang
> sends him to an alternate timeline where **Harumi** lost her **Hanzo** and
> became **Scorpion**, leading the two to bond over their shared grief
> before joining to take on Quan Chi's evil forces."

Here are videos of tower gameplay and ending:

- Scorpion's gameplay and ending:
- Smoke's gameplay and ending:

They confirm the first part cited from Wikipedia.